# PHP SQL I want to show 2 sets of data in 1 row of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I don't really know what I'm doing in PHP.

I can get my data to show like this using the code below

```
Site Name
Name1   07990 111111
Name2   07801 111111
Name3   07887 111111
Name4   07825 111111
Name5   07785 111111
Name6   07778 111111
Name7   07887 111111
Name8   07796 111111
```

But I want it to show more like this but can't find out how to do it, any help please.

```
Site Name
Name1   07990 111111                Name2   07801 111111
Name3   07887 111111                Name4   07825 111111
Name5   07785 111111                Name6   07778 111111
Name7   07887 111111                Name8   07796 111111
```

```
 <?php 
//CONNECT TO THE SERVER
mysql_connect("???", "????", "???") or die ('dead');
//SELECT OUR DB
@mysql_select_db("???") or die ("dead");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE Address='Site Name'"; 

 Print "Site Name";

 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
<?php 
$i=0;
echo "<table border='0'>
 <tr>
 </tr><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
  if($i%2=="0"){echo "</tr><tr>";}

  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

    $i++;}
 echo "</tr></table>";


  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
        if($i%2==0)
                echo "</tr><tr>"; 
        $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
$table = 
"
    <table border='0'>
        <tr>
";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($i%2 == 0 && $i != 0)
    {
        $table .=  "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $table .=
    "
        <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>
    ";
    $i++;
}
$table .= 
"
        </tr>
    </table>
";
echo $table;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go here is either to use two floating tables or to float the rows using CSS. Remember, you want to keep your tables semantically sensible.

#### Using CSS

Generate your table and give your table an ID. The HTML should look something like this:

```
<table class="my_table_id">
    <tr>
        <td>Name 01</td>
        <td>Phone 01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 02</td>
        <td>Phone 02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 03</td>
        <td>Phone 03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 04</td>
        <td>Phone 04</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Next, use CSS to style it. Like this:

```
.my_table_id tr {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bter7ur2/

#### Using two tables

This approach makes the table read down-then-right instead of right-then-down. It's how I would do it since it makes more sense to read a table that way.

Count the total number of rows your query got you, halve that number and insert a break between tables after that number of rows (rounded up). Then you just use CSS to style and float the tables to your liking.

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = $query) {
    $i = (isset($i) ? $i + 1 : 1);    //  Counter that ticks up for each row processed.
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    //  If we've reached half of the number of rows, insert a new table.
    if (count($row) / 2 == $i) {
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<table>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

And a fiddle for this one: http://jsfiddle.net/8fj28vcg/

The HTML can (and should) be polished here to add some ID:s and classes for the CSS to latch on to. Also, don't use mysql, it's deprecated and will not be around for long. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: They all worked, Just have to decide which to use. Thanks for all your help

Comment: The other approaches may work, but they make less semantic sense. One row of data should only be one set of data. Screen readers would not be able to make sense of it.